# How to get the image resized to the with of the window

Tags: css

I have the webpage:

http://www.arlande.nl/oplossingen/project-programma-en-interim-management/interim-management

How to get the image below the titel outlined over the complete window.

It is now inside the container of the template.
I tried several css like position fixed, absolute but cannot find the correct combination.

Any good suggestions?

Comment: If you have an issue with your code, you need to post it here (The relevant part of course, not the whole page).

Comment: The container in which the image is should be made full width.

Comment: Can you put an image outside the container in a different div and make width of div and image 100%.

Comment: Because the width of container is always fixed and if we will change the width of container it will change for all other container section.

Comment: `html, body {width:100%;}` ``.box { min-width:100vw;}` `.box > img{min-width:100%}`

Answer (score 0):

@hunzaboy, thxs. It was the simpelst solution to do that. For anybody who wants to know this is the solution:

```
.term-listing-heading{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.taxonomy-term--oplossingen {
    max-width: none;
}

.taxonomy-term-description{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your question and CSS-only answer are of no help for future readers. You answered with code to a question which link might go dead in short.